Parametrizing Rotations of Minkowski Space $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$ Using $\text{Spin}(1,1)$
I was able to derive that
$$\text{Spin}(1,1)=\{a+be_{12}|a^2-b^2=\pm1\},$$
which has 4 connected components. Individually, they parametrize rotation in each quadrant. Moreover, the map $a+be_{12}\mapsto ae_1+be_2$ is a group isomorphism from $\text{Spin}(1,1)$ to
$$O(1,1)=\{a+be_1|a^2-b^2=\pm1\}.$$ We can quickly then see that $$\text{Spin}^+(1,1)\cong SO(1,1),$$ so $\text{Spin}^+(1,1)$ can be used to represent rotations in $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}.$ My goal is to compactify these 4 components onto $[0,4\pi)\cong S^1,$ as well as the 2 positive components onto $[0,2\pi)\cong S^1.$ However, I'm unsure which order, and which orientation, each component should be given.

The set you call $O(1,1)$ is not a group. Presumably you mean the group generated by this set.

It's not really clear what you want. You can write the elements of $\mathrm{Spin}^+(1,1)$ as exponetials $e^{\xi e_{12}}$ for scalar $\xi$, is that what you want? Then could you write $\xi = \tan(\theta/4-\pi/2)$?

@NicholasTodoroff My apologies, I had the basis elements copied down wrong. Fixed it.

@NicholasTodoroff I've thought on it. The question I'm asking is whether the 2 connected components of a hyperbola have a canonical oriention (positive or negative) and whether the 4 connected components of the two hyperbolas have a canonical ordering when we parametrize them as a whole. Clearly, the identity should be in the first component, and we choose the positive orientation for it. From there, I'm not sure.
